# csv.DictReader to skip first two rows of data

Tags: python

I have a buffer that looks like that:

```
some_random_info
another info here that i dont want to parser
column1,column2,column3
a,b,c
```

I want to read this that using python csv built-in module using the `DictReader` class, but from the docs it says:

```
 class csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None, dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)

    Create an object that operates like a regular reader but maps the information in each row to a dict whose keys are given by the optional fieldnames parameter.

    The fieldnames parameter is a sequence. If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldnames. Regardless of how the fieldnames are determined, the dictionary preserves their original ordering.
```

I have tried that:

```
import io
import csv

buffer = io.StringIO("""
some_random_info
another info here that i dont want to parser
column1,column2,column3
a,b,c   
""")


reader = csv.DictReader(buffer,fieldnames=['column1','column2','column3'])
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

But outputs this:

```
{'column1': 'some_random_info', 'column2': None, 'column3': None}
{'column1': 'another info here that i dont want to parser', 'column2': None, 'column3': None}
{'column1': 'column1', 'column2': 'column2', 'column3': 'column3'}
{'column1': 'a', 'column2': 'b', 'column3': 'c   '}
```

what I'm looking for is just `{'column1': 'a', 'column2': 'b', 'column3': 'c   '}`

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to call `next(buffer)` as many times as needed to skip the extra lines at the start.

Since the first line after that is the header, don't skip it, and don't specify `fieldnames`, just let `DictReader` parse that line to get the field names automatically.

```
import io
import csv

buffer = io.StringIO("""
some_random_info
another info here that I don't want to parse
column1,column2,column3
a,b,c   
""")

for _ in range(3):  # read the first 3 lines
    print("skip:", next(buffer), end="")
# skip:
# skip: some_random_info
# skip: another info here that I don't want to parse

reader = csv.DictReader(buffer)  # read the 4th line to get column names
for row in reader:
    print(row)  # read all remaining lines to get column values
# {'column1': 'a', 'column2': 'b', 'column3': 'c   '}
```

Obviously in the above you don't need to `print()` the `next(buffer)` calls, but for the purposes of the example it helps you see what exactly you're "skipping" with each iteration.

Comment: hum why `next(buffer) * 4` doesn't work ?

Comment: The `*` operator isn't the same as a `for` loop.  If you do that, you'll get the first line by calling `next` once, and then you'll multiply that string by 4.  (Also, as explained in the answer, you don't want to skip 4 lines, just 3.)